# Weex - <list> vs <recycle-list>

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, weex

I am developing an application in Weex using Vue.js.

I am trying to build a `list` component and I was going through the document and in there, there are component which I can use.

1. `<list>`
2. `<recycle-list>`

I couldn't figure out the difference between two as under the hood how do they differ? It could be inffered that `<recycle-list` is more efficient than using a `<list` but the reason is no where mentioned.

Also `<recyle-list>` does not work on web but it works fine on mobile application. What is the reasoning behind that?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

**< list >**

The List component, which inspired by Android RecyclerView, is a core component, and it provides the most popular features for using a list of items. which support vertical and horizontal list.

It can provide excellent experience and performance while still maintaining smooth scroll and low memory usage.

**< recycle-list >**

is a new list container with the ability to recycle and reuse, which can greatly optimize memory usage and rendering performance.

**Web version < recycle-list > is also being developed.** - thus, why it's not working on web right now.

Comment: Thanks! But how does that tell you the difference between the two modules?